# Grails GORM self-referential belongsTo deletes opposite direction from expected

Tags: grails, grails-orm, belongs-to

I have a Grails domain class that is a hierarchy of categories.  Each Category has a parent category (except for the root category which is null).

```
class Category {
    String name

    static mapping = {
        cache true
        name index:'category_name_idx'
    }

    static belongsTo = [parent:Category]

    static constraints = {
        parent(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

My problem:  deletes cascade exactly opposite of what I'd expect:

- someSubCategory.delete() deletes the category then tries to delete the parent category (which fails with an integrity violation if the parent has other children).
- parentCategory.delete() does NOT cascade delete its children, but instead just fails with an integrity violation.

What am I doing wrong?  My understanding is that the 'belongsTo' above should tell the GORM to cascade deletes from the parent to all children, but not from a child to its parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly a Category belongs to a parent and a parent can have multiple children, so I think you need a hasMany relationship, something like this:

```
class Category {
    String name

    static mapping = {
        cache true
        name index:'category_name_idx'
    }

    static belongsTo = [parent:Category]
    static hasMany = [children: Category]

    static constraints = {
        parent(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

I had had similar structures and never have issues with the delete doing it this way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @maricel!  It's obvious in hindsight... feel a little silly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer, but I found a workaround to my own question.  You can remove the belongsTo = [parent:Category], replacing it with a simple instance variable.  This stops subCategory.delete() from cascading to the parent.

```
class Category {
    String name
    Category parent

    static mapping = {
        cache true
        name index:'category_name_idx'
    }

    static constraints = {
        parent(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

Comment: in my team, we solve this problem by the same way. We also include a transient object "childrenCategories" to get the children categories

Comment: Yeah, I added a childrenCategories too.  And to delete the children when the parent is deleted, I implemented the GORM 'beforeDelete' event:  def beforeDelete = {Category.withNewSession{childrenCategories*.delete()} }

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If I know it sooner, I wouldn't have to implement the delete function :)

Comment: Do we have to specify the relationship hasMany for the "childrenCategories" variable? And when do we call the action beforeDelete{}? Because as I see in your implementation, we do not tell Grails to know which category that the childrenCategories belongs to. Or it will be called automatically before deleting the catergory instance?

Comment: @napoleonit76:  For the children I didn't use a variable, but instead a method like this:  def getChildrenCategories() {Category.findAllByParent(this, [sort:'name'])}.  And you don't call beforeDelete:  Grails automatically calls it before doing its built-in delete.